# C# to VB.Net Issue

Tags: c#, vb.net, inheritance, c#-to-vb.net

OK so I am not very fluent in either language so please forgive me if this is a simple question. I am trying to transpose some sample code from C# to VB.net as I am more fluent in VB.Net and want to implement this into an existing project. I have a simple class and a simple form. I am having errors with the inherits line for events.required and am not sure how to solve.

C# works great
MyClass C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using com.handpoint.api;
namespace WindowsGettingStartedApp
{
    class MyClass : Events.Required
    {
        Hapi api;
        Device device;
        private Form1 UIClass;
        public MyClass(Form1 form1)
        {
            InitApi();
            UIClass = form1;
        }
        public void InitApi()
        {
            string sharedSecret = "0102030405060708091011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132";
            api = HapiFactory.GetAsyncInterface(this).DefaultSharedSecret(sharedSecret);
            // The api is now initialized, and we've  set a default shared secret
            // The shared secret is a unique string shared between the card reader and your mobile application.
            // It prevents other people from connecting to your card reader.
            // You should replace this default shared secret by the one sent by our support team.
        }
        public void DiscoverDevices()
        {
            api.ListDevices(ConnectionMethod.BLUETOOTH);
            // This triggers the search for all the bluetooth devices around.
            // You can also search for USB and Serial as a connection method
        }
        public void DeviceDiscoveryFinished(List<Device> devices)
        {
            foreach (Device device in devices)
            {
                if (device.Name != null)
                {
                    if (device.Name.Equals("PP0513901435"))
                    // Put the name of your device, find it by pressing C then up arrow on your card reader keypad
                    {
                        this.device = device;
                        // We'll remember the device for this session, and you should too
                        api.UseDevice(this.device);
                        // Connection to the device is handled automatically in the API
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // You can also connect directly to a specific device without having to discover the other devices around :
        public void DirectConnect()
        {
            Device device = new Device("PP0513901435", "68:AA:D2:00:D5:27", "", ConnectionMethod.BLUETOOTH);
            // The MAC Adress always has to be written in UPPER CASE
            // new Device("name", "address", "port", ConnectionMethod);
            api.UseDevice(device);
        }
        public bool Pay()
        {
            return api.Sale(new BigInteger("1000"), Currency.GBP);
            // Let´s start our first payment of 10 pounds
        }
        public void SignatureRequired(SignatureRequest signatureRequest, Device device)
        {
            // You'll be notified here if a sale process needs a signature verification
            // A signature verification is needed if the cardholder uses an MSR or a chip & signature card
            // This method will not be invoked if a transaction is made with a Chip & PIN card
            api.SignatureResult(true); // This line means that the cardholder ALWAYS accepts to sign the receipt.
            // A specific line will be displayed on the merchant receipt for the cardholder to be able to sign it
        }
        public void EndOfTransaction(TransactionResult transactionResult, Device device)
        {
            UIClass.DisplayReceipts(transactionResult.MerchantReceipt, transactionResult.CustomerReceipt);
        }
        public void Disconnect()
        {
            api.Disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

C# works great Form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsGettingStartedApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MyClass my;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            my = new MyClass(this);
        }
        private void PayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            my.Pay();
        }
        private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            my.DiscoverDevices();
            // my.DirectConnect();
        }
        private void DisconnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            my.Disconnect();
        }
        public delegate void UpdateReceiptsCallback(string MerchantReceipt, string CustomerReceipt);
        public void DisplayReceipts(string MerchantReceipt, string CustomerReceipt)
        {
            // Only need to check for one of the webBrowsers
            if (MerchantReceiptBrowser.InvokeRequired)
            {
                UpdateReceiptsCallback d = new UpdateReceiptsCallback(DisplayReceipts);
                this.Invoke(d, new object[] { MerchantReceipt, CustomerReceipt });
            }
            else
            {
                MerchantReceiptBrowser.DocumentText = MerchantReceipt;
                CardholderReceiptBrowser.DocumentText = CustomerReceipt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My VB.Net MyClass Conversion

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports com.handpoint.api
Namespace WindowsGettingStartedApp

Class [MyClass]
    Inherits Events.Required
```

**The above line gets the error: Classes can inherit only from other classes**

```
    Private api As Hapi
    Private device As Device
    Private UIClass As Form1
    Public Sub New(form1 As Form1)
        InitApi()
        UIClass = form1
    End Sub
    Public Sub InitApi()
        Dim sharedSecret As String = "0102030405060708091011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132"
        api = HapiFactory.GetAsyncInterface(Me).DefaultSharedSecret(sharedSecret)
        ' The api is now initialized, and we've  set a default shared secret
        ' The shared secret is a unique string shared between the card reader and your mobile application.
        ' It prevents other people from connecting to your card reader.
        ' You should replace this default shared secret by the one sent by our support team.
    End Sub
    Public Sub DiscoverDevices()
        api.ListDevices(ConnectionMethod.BLUETOOTH)
        ' This triggers the search for all the bluetooth devices around.
        ' You can also search for USB and Serial as a connection method
    End Sub
    Public Sub DeviceDiscoveryFinished(devices As List(Of Device))
        For Each device As Device In devices
            If device.Name IsNot Nothing Then
            If device.Name.Equals("PP0513901435") Then
                    ' Put the name of your device, find it by pressing C then up arrow on your card reader keypad
                    Me.device = device
                    ' We'll remember the device for this session, and you should too
                        ' Connection to the device is handled automatically in the API
                    api.UseDevice(Me.device)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
    ' You can also connect directly to a specific device without having to discover the other devices around :
    Public Sub DirectConnect()
        Dim device As New Device("PP0513901435", "68:AA:D2:00:D5:27", "", ConnectionMethod.BLUETOOTH)
        ' The MAC Adress always has to be written in UPPER CASE
        ' new Device("name", "address", "port", ConnectionMethod);
        api.UseDevice(device)
    End Sub
    Public Function Pay() As Boolean
        Return api.Sale(New BigInteger("1000"), Currency.GBP)
        ' Let´s start our first payment of 10 pounds
    End Function
    Public Sub SignatureRequired(signatureRequest As SignatureRequest, device As Device)
        ' You'll be notified here if a sale process needs a signature verification
        ' A signature verification is needed if the cardholder uses an MSR or a chip & signature card
        ' This method will not be invoked if a transaction is made with a Chip & PIN card
        api.SignatureResult(True)
        ' This line means that the cardholder ALWAYS accepts to sign the receipt.
        ' A specific line will be displayed on the merchant receipt for the cardholder to be able to sign it
    End Sub

    Public Sub EndOfTransaction(transactionResult As TransactionResult, device As Device)
        UIClass.DisplayReceipts(transactionResult.MerchantReceipt, transactionResult.CustomerReceipt)
    End Sub
    Public Sub Disconnect()
        api.Disconnect()
    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

My VB.Net Form1

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Namespace WindowsGettingStartedApp
Public Partial Class Form1
    Inherits Form
    Private my As [MyClass]
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
```

**The above line is giving me the error 'InitializeComponent' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
I get the above error when referencing objects on the form as well.**

```
        my = New [MyClass](Me)
    End Sub
    Private Sub PayButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        my.Pay()
    End Sub
    Private Sub ConnectButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        my.DiscoverDevices()
        ' my.DirectConnect();
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisconnectButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        my.Disconnect()
    End Sub
    Public Delegate Sub UpdateReceiptsCallback(MerchantReceipt As String, CustomerReceipt As String)
    Public Sub DisplayReceipts(MerchantReceipt As String, CustomerReceipt As String)
        ' Only need to check for one of the webBrowsers
        If MerchantReceiptBrowser.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New UpdateReceiptsCallback(AddressOf DisplayReceipts)
            Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {MerchantReceipt, CustomerReceipt})
        Else
            MerchantReceiptBrowser.DocumentText = MerchantReceipt
            CardholderReceiptBrowser.DocumentText = CustomerReceipt
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
End Namespace
```

My Form1.Designer.vb

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    components = New System.ComponentModel.Container
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.Text = "Form1"
End Sub
End Class
```

Any insight would be great. I am sure I am missing something simple but again am a newbie. I bolded the spots where I am getting the errors. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please fix your post so that you don't double-space the code.

Answer (score 5):

The first error is because `Events.Required` is an interface so it should read

```
 Implements Events.Required
```

instead of

```
 Inherits Events.Required
```

The second error is because `InitializeComponent` is declared in the form designer file which you may not have included / translated in your application. Add a new form to your project if you want to inspect what this should look like.

Comment: Thanks for this. The impliments is still giving an error. Now says the sub must be included which they are. I think you are on to something with the designer. What I did was created a new form. Than I simply copied and pasted the above code. I assume I am missing something on the form designer but not sure what. Thanks for the direction. I will see what else I can find. I have added the designer code above if it provides any insight. Thanks again.

Comment: After each member of the interface you need to add `implements events.required.whatever` . see a tutorial on interfaces for an example.